# Wrong access .data segment

Tags: x86, pe, disassemblers, game-hacking, game

## Preface

I'm a PHP programmer, in my spare time I've been doing reverse work. Achieved good progress in the analysis game. But there was a big problem on my way. And now, more than ever, i need the help of the most powerful community to clarify my mistake.

## Problem

Trying to increase the amount of text, I came across an error when the game just crashes.
The section code is below:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Offset (0046A1EC):

```
.text:0046A1EC push offset aEnaPokupkiSPix
```

Trying to increase the offset index beyond zone 2 results in a game crash, but if the index is in zone 1 or higher, everything works fine.

[image]

I really don't know where to search anymore :(

## Given

- **Game**: “Recettear: An Item Shop's Tale” [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/70400/)
- **Translation language**: Russian (UNICODE)
- **Original language**: English (SHIFT-JIS)
- **Data storage format**: fileDataIdx + fileDataBuffer
- **Translation group**: [Recettear: An Item Shop's Tale](https://vk.com/recettear_an_item_shops_tale)

## Was done

1. Using **PE Explorer**, I changed the partition type from `.extra` to `.data`.
2. With the help of **PE Explorer** increased the virtual volume of the partition to (`F4240`).

   [image]
3. With the help of **IDA PRO** added support for `UNICODE`
4. Made a program for editing fonts

   [image]
5. Translated some internal texts that were in the exe file.

   [image]

Help who can, at least in which direction to search:(

Comment: What is "zone 1" and "zone 2"? The hex view shows the bytes as patched in the IDB, but are they patched in the file on disk?

Comment: Yea, they patched on disk

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, today I continued the experiments, and I got the impression that it breaks at the substitution stage in sprintf()